# how to seal hole in hvac chamber

Tags: hvac

My Hvac a/c heater duct chamber has a giant hole. apparently, the previosu owner had cut a rectanglar hold and then tried to seal it with aluminium sheet. Its leaking on the side and i cut open the dry wall above to see it.
how can i seal this hole properly so it does not leak?
[image]

Comment: metal tape or red devil F-Seal 181 or can use rectorseal.  depends on access.